# Complex sort expression in ravendb or elastic search

Tags: database, sorting, lucene, ravendb

I'm trying to develop an advanced sort expression, but can't figure out how this can be done. The query can be done on elastic search or in ravendb (or lucene expression). The preference is to use ravendb, that is I intent to have all the data, but if the is no way to do that on ravendb, the elastic search will be an alternative.
The main idea is to have have "score" on some field values, so we can pass this score values and have custom sorts of the results.

A product list look like this (concept):

```
{
name: 'product 1',
brand: 1,
filters: [1, 2, 7, 10]
},{
name: 'product 2',
brand: 2,
filters: [1, 3, 7, 15]
},{
name: 'product 3',
brand: 2,
filters: [1, 2, 8, 10]
},{
name: 'product 4',
brand: 3,
filters: [2, 8, 10]
}
```

**I want to pass to query the score of brand and filter, like that:**

Brand 1: score 10

Brand 2: score 15

Filter 1: score 10

Filter 3: score 5

Filter 10: score 8

**With this, I will get the following sorted product list:**

Product 3: 15 (brand 2) + 10 (filter 1) + 8 (filter 10) = 33

Product 2: 15 (brand 2) + 10 (filter 1) + 5 (filter 3) = 30

Product 1: 10 (brand 1) + 10 (filter 1) + 8 (filter 10) = 28

Product 4: 8 (filter 10) = 8

**This query need to be dynamic, so I can send the next query like this:**

Brand 1: score 10

Brand 2: score 15

Brand 3: 16

Filter 1: score 5

Filter 3: score 5

Filter 10: score 1

**And the sorted results will change:**

Product 2: 15 (brand 2) + 5 (filter 1) + 5 (filter 3) = 25

Product 3: 15 (brand 2) + 5 (filter 1) + 1 (filter 10) = 21

Product 4: 16 (brand 3) + 1 (filter 10) = 17

Product 1: 10 (brand 1) + 5 (filter 1) + 1 (filter 10) = 16

There is any query of ravendb, lucene ou elastic search that I can get this sorted results, without need to loop them (because will be a lot of queries at same time)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know you did not include Solr in you question as a possibility, but being so close to Lucene/ElasticSearch I will throw it out there in case you might consider it.

This can be done in Solr with [Function Queries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries). Using `sum`, `if` and `termfreq` should be enough to build the expression you want (and I am sure there are other combinations that achieve it too).